# Selenium Looping Dynamic Drop Downs with Submit in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been banging away at this for about a day and a half now but I cannot seem to make any headway. I am new to Selenium and am currently trying to collect data from a dynamic web app where BeautifulSoup (my typical go-to) is not an option as there are no static urls. The app I am scraping is an auto parts catalog and I need to select the first available year, which loads the available makes, select the first make, which loads the available models, select the first model, then click submit, scrape the data that results, then go back and do the next model. When all models are done, move on to the next make and start on more models. When all the models are done, move to the next year, then do all available makes, then models. My nested for-loops are as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

def make_waitfor_elem_updated_predicate(driver, 
    waitfor_elem_xpath_select):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(waitfor_elem_xpath_select)

def elem_updated(driver):
    try:
        elem.text
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return True
    except:
        pass

    return False

return lambda driver: elem_updated(driver)

class Partbot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.home_page = 'http://monroe-px.rtrk.com/en-US/e-catalog'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.year_xpath = '//select[@id="widget-ymm-year-desktop"]'
        self.make_xpath = '//select[@id="widget-ymm-make-desktop"]'
        self.model_xpath = '//select[@id="widget-ymm-model-desktop"]'

    def get_select(self, xpath_select):
        select_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_select)
        select = Select(select_elem)
        return select

    def select_option(self, xpath_select, value, 
                 waitfor_elem_xpath_select=None):
        if waitfor_elem_xpath_select:
            func = make_waitfor_elem_updated_predicate(
                       self.driver,
                       waitfor_elem_xpath_select
                   )

        select = self.get_select(xpath_select)
        select.select_by_value(value)

        return self.get_select(xpath_select)

    def make_select_option_iterator(self, xpath_select, 
                             waitfor_elem_xpath_select):

        def next_option(xpath_select_select, 
                  waitfor_elem_xpath_select):
            select = self.get_select(xpath_select)
            select_option_values = [
                 '{}'.format(op.get_attribute('value'))
                  for op
                  in select.options[1:]
                  ]
            for v in select_option_values:
                select = self.select_option(xpath_select, v, 
                                   waitfor_elem_xpath_select)
                yield select.first_selected_option.text

        return lambda: next_option(xpath_select, 
                      waitfor_elem_xpath_select)

    def load_page(self):
        self.driver.get(self.home_page)

        def page_loaded(driver):
            path = '//select[@id="widget-ymm-year-desktop"]'
            return driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)

        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        wait.until(page_loaded)

    def are_extras_present(self):
        extras = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*
                  [contains(@id, 'widget-ymm-moreinfo')]")
        if len(extras) >= 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def scrape_items(self):
        years = self.make_select_option_iterator(
            self.year_xpath,
            self.make_xpath
        )

        makes = self.make_select_option_iterator(
            self.make_xpath,
            self.model_xpath
        )

        models = self.make_select_option_iterator(
            self.model_xpath,
            None
        )

        self.load_page()

        try:
            for year in years():
                print(year)
                for make in makes():
                    print(2*' ', make)
                    for model in models():
                        print(4*' ', model)
                        subm = 
self.driver.find_element_by_id('lookup-form-desktop')
                      subm.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
                      time.sleep(2)


            except:
                self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pb = Partbot()
        pb.scrape_items()
```

Comment: What about setting the values of the the models, etc, right before clicking the button? Also why the infinite loop? Maybe include your helper functions in your question too

Comment: the while loop is something I was playing with and didn't mean to post in the code. I will revise.

Comment: Revisions posted along with the rest of the class and helper functions. I tried adding the values again before the button click, but then all three loops simply exit and the program stops. Not really sure where I am going wrong but it is quite frustrating. I'm new to Selenium so I may be grasping at straws here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Quick suggestion: either get rid of the try catch or print the exception before shutting down the driver. Knowing what selenium is complaining about will probably help a lot.

Comment: You can detect requests that page makes in `network` tab in chrome dev tools. If you simulate those request you can get the direct response in json format. [example1](http://catalog.monroe.com/catalog/catalogOptions.do?selectedCatalogId=949&selection=year), [example2](http://catalog.monroe.com/catalog/catalogOptions.do?selectedCatalogId=949&selectedYear=43893&selectedMakeId=null&selection=make).

Comment: Is there a particular set of documentation or a tutorial on how to submit responses via JSON? Also, would I be able to scrape the resulting content via Beautiful soup?

Comment: I don't know about documentation it more depends on practice. If you open `Network` tab in dev tools you can spot that each time when you select the year or make or model  - page generates a [request](http://icecream.me/86c9ff0b189db66b2c0b73e8d36690d8) to the server and has json response in return.
For parsing json response you don't need `bs4` you can use a library `Requests` which has [built-in json decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).